# Extending HP Quality Center using Groovy and Jacob

Tags: groovy, jacob, hp-quality-center

I am trying to interface with HP Quality Center using Groovy with a Jacob COM wrapper, but I am running into problems.

When I try to run the following code:

```
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent
import com.jacob.com.*

def QCUrl = "http://qc.example.com/qcbin"
def QCcom = new ActiveXComponent("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
def conQC = QCcom.getObject()
Dispatch.call(conQC, 'InitConnectionEx', QCUrl)
```

I get this exception:

```
com/jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: InitConnectionEx
```

The HP Quality Center OTA makes it clear that `InitConnectionEx` is the method that I am interested in; however, I feel like I am missing a step somewhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much google time, I have come to the fix to my issue.  The error was happening because I was not starting SoapUI with Admin rights.

Apparently, if the application you are running does not have admin rights, then it cannot create the necessary ActiveXObjects.  When I would try to instantiate an ActiveXObject, I would not get any error, but the TDConnection object wasn't created and therefore InitConnectionEx was not present.

After starting SoapUI with admin rights, I am able to connect.

I got the idea from reading this [article](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-Quality-Center-Forum/ActiveX-component-can-t-create-object-TDApiOle80-TDConnection/td-p/4742677).

Answer (score 2):

I once had the questionable pleasure to work with Quality Center and its API. I didn't use Jacob directly, but the Groovy [Scriptom](http://groovy.codehaus.org/COM+Scripting) module, which makes the COM scripting much more bearable. With Scriptom the code to connect to QC looks like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*

Scriptom.inApartment
{
    def tdc = new ActiveXObject ('TDApiOle80.TDConnection')
    tdc.InitConnectionEx('http://qc.example.com/qcbin')
    tdc.Login('user', 'password')
    tdc.Connect('domain','project')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Christoph.  I really like Scriptom's syntax over the bare Jacob interface.  However, after getting everything setup and running the above code example, I am still getting the: `com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: InitConnectionEx` error.  Any advice?